# Changing display (UI) / order of items Observable Collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

EDIT #2:

```
    public void ReverseOrderRegBtns()
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GlobalObservableCol.regBtns);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ReverseOrder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        view.Refresh();
    }
```

Not really sure how to fit the ICollectionView in, it also interrupts timers that are doing some logic. For some reason it interupts my timing that starts counting when a button gets created.

*My application has several timers, so the buttons that get created get updates with possible new content every x amount of seconds.*

EDIT:

The databinding looks as following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbRegistration" ItemsSource="{Binding regBtnsReverse, ElementName=Window}" Background="{x:Null}"
```

**Old:**
     public ObservableCollection RegBtns
            { 
                get
                {
                    if (GlobalObservableCol.regBtns == null)
                    {
                        return new ObservableCollection();
                    }
                    return GlobalObservableCol.regBtns;
                }
            }

**New (no longer works), the reverse is in the ObserableCol class**

```
public IEnumerable<RegistrationButton> RegBtns
        {
            get
            {
                return GlobalObservableCol.regBtnsReverse;
            }
        }
```

I have created the IEnumerable in my a static class where the ObservableCollection list is available.

*I cannot seem to bind when my databinding is a IENumerable. How to bind the NumbersReverse
 method that is located in a other class to my MainWindow.xls?*

---

I have a ObservableCollection that holds custom styled WPF buttons.

Those items get dynamically created and added on a custom slider control (listbox).
For example Button 1, Button 2, Button 3, ...

What i want is exactly the **opposite**.

*For example Button 3, Button 2, Button 1.*
This sounds like a linked list but my entire application is already using this Observable Collection throughout the entire logic.

When the buttons get displayed in the UI the last added button should be placed as the first item on my slider (that is a listbox control).

How exactly can i pull this off?

Thanks,
PeterP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}"/>

private ObservableCollection<RegButtton> RegBtns = new...;

public ICollectionView Foo { get; set; }

Foo = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(RegBtns);
Foo.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SomePropertyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
Foo.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code there should be `myCollection.Add( someButton )`.

Replace it with `myCollection.Insert( 0, myButton )` and you're finished.

Comment: That actually works and replaces the button at the first index but it breaks my entire logic I'm afraid. My program no longer works when doing this.

Comment: well if the rest of the program depends on the button's order, changing just the display order like Michal says is definitely the best solution

Comment: its a design issue. im means of seperation of concern paradigm or by means of n-tier model you should not modify data for presentations purpose. use views and/or adapters for it - viewmodel in wpf.

Comment: good point but depends on the complexity imo; eg if the OP has a collection of buttons just for the sake of having a collection and nothing is done with the collection except displaying it, I'd be happy with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what framework you use. I would do something like in my view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers { get; private set; }
public IEnumerable<int> NumbersReverse
{
    get
    {
        return Numbers.Reverse();
    }

}
```

and I would use NumbersReverse as a datasource:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding NumbersReverse}"/>
```

Of course there are many other ways of doing that. You have to figure out what's best in your case...

Edit:
e.g. if you do not care about the order of the items for any other purpose, then the solution provided by stijn is much better.

Comment: I cannot seem to get to do .Reverse on my static ObservableCollection<customBtn>

Comment: Maybe it's because you use older version of .NET framework. Reverse on IEnumerable<T> was introduced in .NET framework 3.5. You can change the version of your framework or you can create another NumbersReverse property and initialize it in a for loop taking the elements from the last to the first and inserting them in your new list.

Comment: The databinding happends at the moment trough a singleton method, maybe thats why i am having problems? When i replace the method with a IEnumerable and databand i get no visible button.

Comment: change notification will screw you here. if the collection changes you wont get the notifications.